# How to emulate Google's thick, red underline text decoration

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, border, text-decorations

[image: Red Google border]

I'm trying to emulate the look of the above red text-decoration (beneath "Web") using [this code](http://www.bootply.com/kYbrVFNsQy).

Here it is again.

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>  

                    </ul><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
                </div><!-- END: "container" -->
            </div><!-- END: "container" -->
        </div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff; 
  text-decoration: underline 3px;
  border-bottom:4px solid #ebebeb
}
```

The thickness of mine I think is optimal, and the color too, however, when you look at it, you can see that there is a really small gap between that white border and the navbar, and that the border is too long, and so I'm wondering

1. How to get rid of that gap, causing the border to "fuse" with the white background.
2. Decreasing the length of my border, which seems to correspond with the width of the highlighted box behind it.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.bootply.com/ALMTcN9yFG) a way of doing it assuming you don't mind using the `box-shadow` property.

Apply a set height to match the list items to the navbar.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li { height: 52px; background: #080808; }
```

And then add a box shadow with no blur and a negative spread to the anchors.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 14px 0px -10px #dbdbdb;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 14px 0px -10px #dbdbdb;
    box-shadow:         0px 14px 0px -10px #dbdbdb;
}
```

Regarding your other question, I've noticed in the past that the "gap" you're referring to seems to vary depending on the browser. The only way I've been able to eliminate it was with a negative margin, but maybe someone else has a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. About that margin, yeah, where would I define it as negative?

Comment: No problem, looking at your original bootply you could apply it to `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li { margin-bottom: -1px; }`

Answer (score 0):

1. set `margin:0;`
2. The border of an element takes its entire width and/or height. If you want it to be smaller, you might want to replace that border with a `div` and `position:absolute` (hence set your container to `position:absolute`). Then set your new `div` to `bottom:0;` and choose the `width` that suits you best.